# Preserving order of edges for adding edge weights to a Networkx graph

Tags: python-3.x, graph, networkx

I've the following graph,

```
ed_ls = [(0, 1), (0, 63), (1, 2), (1, 3), (54, 0)]
ed_w = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(ed_ls)
edge_w = OrderedDict(zip(G.edges, ed_w))
nx.set_edge_attributes(G, edge_w, 'weight')

print(G.edges)
print(nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight'))
```

Output obtained:

```
{(0, 1): 1, (0, 63): 2, (0, 54): 3, (1, 2): 4, (1, 3): 5}
```

The edge weights in `ed_w` are in the same order of edges in `ed_ls`. Since the order of edges
is not preserved, wrong edge weights are assigned. I could use `nx.DiGraph` to avoid this problem. However, I want to use `nx.k_core` later on and this doesn't work on directed graphs. Suggestions on
how to go ahead will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this by using [`Graph.add_weighted_edges_from`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.DiGraph.add_weighted_edges_from.html):

```
ed_ls = [(0, 1), (0, 63), (1, 2), (1, 3), (54, 0)]
ed_w = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_weighted_edges_from(((*edge, w) for edge, w in zip(ed_ls, ed_w)))

G.edges(data=True)
EdgeDataView([(0, 1, {'weight': 1}), (0, 63, {'weight': 2}), 
              (0, 54, {'weight': 5}), (1, 2, {'weight': 3}), 
              (1, 3, {'weight': 4})])
```

If you're using a python version above 3.7, dictionaries maintain insertion order, but the order you seen when printing `G.edges(data=True)` is not necessarily the order in which edges where added, it rather agrees with node adding. As you can see in this example `(54, 0)` is shown before
`(1, 2)` since node `0` was added before.

Comment: Thanks. How do we add multiple edge attributes?  `nx.set_edge_attributes(G, edge_w, 'weight1')`  ,  `nx.set_edge_attributes(G, edge_w, 'weight2')` I could set multiple attributes here. May I know how to do this via `add_weighted_edges_from`

Comment: `add_weighted_edges_from` just expected `(source, target, weight)`. It isn't meant for adding more attributes @Natasha so you'd need to either set those parameters at insertion time, i.e `G.add_edge(source, target, attr1=8, attr2=4, ...)`, or with `set_edge_attributes`

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you assign the weights to the edges at the time of adding them to the graph?

```py
ed_ls = [(0, 1), (0, 63), (1, 2), (1, 3), (54, 0)]
ed_w = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
G = nx.Graph()

for i in range(len(ed_ls)):
    src, dst = ed_ls[i]
    G.add_edge(src, dst, weight=ed_w[i])
```

Comment: Thank you. How do we add 2 weights?

Comment: Didn't get you? What do you mean by adding 2 weights?

Comment: Sorry, if I wasn't clear. I meant multiple edge attributes.